# TextRecognize from image not detecting other language

Tags: java, android

I was trying to detect the text from image using com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision. It is working fine in detecting english language but not for other language. How to specify the language to detect text. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what language are you trying to detect?

Comment: there's a list of valid languages here https://developers.google.com/vision/documentation/android/text-overview

Comment: Any language like tamil, chinese, japanese etc it is depends on the users

Comment: that's not how it works. the link above shows the supported languages of the service. Anything outside this list is unknown to the algorithm.

Comment: Is there anyother way to recognize the text. Please suggest.

Comment: I think you have 2 problems in hand. The first one is to detect the language (there are some libraries around to do so, probably based on some vocabulary files) and the second one is to perform the actual OCR thing, which highly depends on models trained with several types of alphabets and types. This last one probably only will have good quality for more popular (commercial) languages. It's a big job to train these models. So I'd suggest you to restrict your scope to something more specific.